# Getting &gt; symbol in query of kohana ORM

Tags: kohana, kohana-3, kohana-orm, kohana-db

I am using the following code

```
    $rooms = $room->join('events', 'LEFT')
                  ->on('rooms.id', '=', 'events.room_id')
                  ->where('events.room_id', 'IS', NULL)
                  ->and_where_open()
                  ->and_where('events.eventstart' , '>', $from)
                  ->or_where('events.eventsstart', '<', $to)
                  ->and_where_close()
                  ->find_all();
    echo $room->last_query(); exit;
```

But in query i get `&gt;` instead of > sign

```
SELECT `rooms`.* FROM `rooms` 
LEFT JOIN `events` ON (`rooms`.`id` = `events`.`room_id`) 
WHERE `events`.`room_id` IS NULL 
AND (`events`.`eventstart` &gt; 1312401600 OR `events`.`eventsstart` &lt; 1312408800)
```

Dont know why???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Mistake

The column name used in or_where was wrong. Thats why i was getting `&gt;` sign in my query

Thanks Kemo for guiding me in other direction.